# php-fpm and lithium/console/li3: permission denied

Tags: php, lithium

I have a problem with php-fpm and li3 console
I config the server following this article: http://www.geoffstratton.com/2014/05/ubuntu-14-apache-php/
It runs well, but every time I call the command it returns error

```
$ ../libraries/lithium/console/li3
bash: ../libraries/lithium/console/li3: Permission denied
```

Please help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check folders and file permissions and owner as well?

Comment: I chmod all files to 644 and directories to 755. I also run the command with the same user as scripts owner.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I solve this problem:
I mounted the file system with noexec option, then it's not able to run any executable files.
I have to remove noexec from mount script in /etc/fstab and remount it. It works now.

Thank you.